# Qt Widget automatically resize if it contains empty layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget

I have been given a qt widget containing some elements and layouts. 
I am trying to add an empty layout to this main widget (My plan is to populate it with a widget in the future). I am expecting the main widget to resize automatically if the layout is empty. How can I do that?
I tried to play on the size policies of the widget but I did not get much results so far .

In the end the idea is to get the main widget (which is not contained in a layout by the way) to resize automatically if it contains an empty layout in itself

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can look for [adjustSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize) method of `QWidget`.
When you add or remove any internal widget in layout, you can make something like this:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(slotAdjustSize()));

...

void YourWidget::slotAdjustSize()
{
    adjustSize();
}
```

Size of your widget will be fit to its contents.